# inherit WPF window, why i can not see the Parent's buttons in the child's window

Tags: wpf, windows, inheritance

i have a base WPF window and a second WPF window which derived from it.
if i add new items to the child's window, i can not see the buttons that derived from the base window anymore.

anyone? idea???
thanx! tali

Comment: Typically they are referred to as "Parent" and "Child" rather than father/son.

Answer (score 0):

There is no visual inheritance in WPF. You should use a UserControl instead.

Edit:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyUserControl">
  <StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Push me" Click="MyClickHandlerInUserControl" />
  </StackPanle>
</UserControl>
```

You can use this UserControl in any View e.g:

```
<Window x:Class="MyWindow"
     xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.MyUserControls" >
  <StackPanel>
    <uc:MyUserControl /> <!--You can use any properties you have declared in your usercontrol -->
    <Button Content="Some other Button" Click="MyClickHandlerInWindow" />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: how to use it? i have the buttons which  want that will be common in all windows (with their logic)
thanx!

Comment: @talia: Share more details on tha button and the logic used.

Comment: buttons "OK" and "Cancel". send a report to the main program about the progress of the sub WPF windows.

Comment: @talia: Yeah, without more informations about the button and it's logic it's gonna be difficult...
See my edit above..